# Как читать и записывать файлы в приложении на swift

Tags: swift

Не могу найти подходящее решение по чтению и записи файлов в приложении iOS: чтобы открывалось окно менеджера с возможностью изменения директории и выбора файлов. Нашел только передачу файлов по заранее известным именам через код или просмоторщик файлов без возможности переноса данных для работы в своем приложение.
В qt creator есть простой класс для решения такой задачи - QFileDialog
Я новенький в swift, так что не судите строго, если вопрос покажется вам глупым

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите UIDocumentPickerViewController. Из документации:

```
// Create a document picker for directories.
let documentPicker =
    UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeFolder as String],
                                   in: .open)

documentPicker.delegate = self

// Set the initial directory.
documentPicker.directoryURL = startingDirectory

// Present the document picker.
present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А как записать открытый файл в массив например? kUTTypeFolder заменил на "public.data" поскольку Xcode ругался. Попробовал достать url, но все попытки окрашивали поле ошибками